# Hibernate and flush: update throws duplicate key error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, flush

I want to change a unique key from one entity object to another in one `@Transaction` method:

```
Entity oldone=dao.getEntity(oldid);
Entity newone=dao.getEntity(newid);
oldone.setBarcode(null);
dao.update(oldone); //free the unique key "barcode"
newone.setBarcode(barcode);
dao.update(newone); //set the unique key "barcode"
```

But this code throws: **Duplicate entry for key 'barcode'**
Dubugging I found that after the first dao.update nothing changes in the database.
I tryed to set the hibernate flushmode to "always" but didn't change:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>             
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">always</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Why hibernate doesn't flush?

Comment: Seems that <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">always</prop> is completely ignored because if I add "session.flush()" after the update, everything works.

Comment: Why u Write this Properties two times ? <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

Comment: Just a CTRL-C CTRL-V error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this Hibernate property is only a hint to Hibernate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558536/difference-between-flushmode-auto-and-flushmode-always-in-hibernate) and in [Hibernate ORM Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/), where they say

> Except when you explicitly flush(), there are absolutely no guarantees
>   about when the Session executes the JDBC calls, only the order in
>   which they are executed.

More to this, the [FlushMode.ALWAYS enum value Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#ALWAYS) states that

> The Session is flushed before every query. This is almost always unnecessary and inefficient.

I'm not sure if by "query" they mean only a database interrogation (reads) or any kind of operation, including inserts, updates and deletes.

If I were you, I would explicitly place a `session.flush()` call after the first update. I know that declarative way is cleaner, but sometimes imperative programming makes your business safer.

Comment: I will choice between an AUTO (i don't know what it is doing) and a ALWAYS (abosolutely without guarantees of when its is flushed)... wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Force this session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of work, before committing the transaction and closing the session (depending on flush-mode, Transaction.commit() calls this method).

When making new objects persistent flush() and then clear() the session regularly in order to control the size of the first-level cache.

[Batch Processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

[Look this.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

IT States that When **Tx.commit();** occurs then the Flush function is called. to No need to even Write that function.

Comment: I still don't understand hibernate.flushMode=always property

Comment: If flush mode is 'AUTO' before firing any query hibernate will check if there are any tables to be updated. If so, flush will be done otherwise no. If flush mode is 'ALWAYS', flush will happen even if there are no tables to be updated.

Comment: Seems this is the theory but not what it is really doing.

Comment: @Tobia Its Something like that only when default Flush mode will be NEVER but after it enter process it becomes AUTO. and According to you r Requirement u can set it. that is all it is. mostly.